# How to make Qt Creator use KDEs color scheme

Tags: kde, qtcreator

I have krita-darker color scheme as my KDE color scheme, but the text area in Qt Creator is still white. How can I force Qt Creator to use KDE color scheme (like Kate)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ask QtCreator to load libraries provided by KDE, e.g

`QT_PLUGIN_PATH="$QT_PLUGIN_PATH:/usr/lib/qt4/plugins/:/usr/lib/kde4/plugins" qtcreator`

If that doesn't work, try set a different color scheme directly,

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! :D I don't want to set a different color scheme in Qt, I still use the default one, so I don't have to change it again if I change the KDE scheme. I want to have those things as system wide as possible :P